# MySQL looks different on Mac?

Tags: mysql, database

I am a self taught front-end dev and I would like to create a MySQL database for a website. I am following a tutorial on youtube, however, it seems that the interface of MySQL on Mac is totally different and it is not possible to code.

Is there any way to be able to code like in the second picture? I really hate the Mac Version.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzPHI.png)

[What I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wIY1.png)

Comment: Anyone around? thanks

Comment: Those are not MySQL, but some graphical MySQL client applications. [There are tons of them](https://www.slant.co/topics/53/~best-mysql-client-applications-for-windows), I can't tell which one from a screenshot. If your tutorial relies on a specific MySQL client, it should tell you which one and how to get it.